# Should I get my guitar re-set up when changing string brands, but not gauges?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, strings

So I've recently purchased an electric guitar, and I've been playing contentedly with it. However, I decided the factory strings were due for a change, so I had the guitar set up with strings of a certain gauge.

Now, however, I've come to regret my choice of string. They just don't sound as good as the original strings from the factory. Therefore, my question is: can I just change the strings to the same gauge, or should I get the whole guitar re-set up, given that the brand might be slightly different or whatnot?

Answer (score 2):

Same gauge strings = same set up. Same string mass, same tension, same speaking length. However... if you had the set up changed from original, which you liked, just changing brand will probably not do it for you.  Sounds like you need to revert to the original string gauge, which will require a re-set-up.

Comment: I just hit the up, but the core of a setup is setting the intonation, and you can do that (more than likely) with a long phillips-head screwdriver and an electronic tuner. The action shouldn't be too different, so you don't need to adjust saddle height or the truss rod, much less change the nut.

Answer (score 0):

Changing string brand while keeping the same gauge does not *theoretically* require a setup. Practically, you may still have to do some minor adjustments to the intonation.

Now the point is that even if you keep the same gauge **and** brand you'll have to adjust your setup frequently if you want to keep your guitar playable and well intonated, so you'd better learn how to do it by yourself. Also, no guitar tech is going to have exactly your hands and touch.